# BB Push Notification service

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

I have to write a Java program which will push a message from my BB device to a push service on the server.

Can any one please provide me any Java code for doing this or any link where I can get information regarding this? I am completely new to the BB push service.

Comment: This can be closed as unclear, too broad, or a request for third-party resources.

Answer (score 0):

The BlackBerry developer blog [has a good intro](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/03/introducing-blackberry-push-services-to-developers/) to the BlackBerry push service, and the developer docs have a whole section on the [BlackBerry Push Service SDK](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/subcategories/?userType=21&category=BlackBerry%20Push%20Service%20SDK) so you can start hacking.